# transform: scale immensely slow in all versions of firefox

Tags: performance, firefox, css

Please check this:

http://users.telenet.be/prullen/grid.html

This has a normal speed in safari, but the zoom effect is really slow in firefox.

Interestingly, if I add:

```
.item {
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
}
```

it seems to speed up a little (still not completely fluent). But that is not the size my images are at, so it looks messed up:

http://users.telenet.be/prullen/grid2.html

If I set the item width/height to the size of my images, thing slow down again:

```
.item {
      width:160px;
      height:160px;
}
```

http://users.telenet.be/prullen/grid3.html

Any ideas as that what is the reason of this? I'm out of ideas, I've removed/added statements but nothing seems to help. This is tested in different firefox versions up to version 10.

Thanks,
Wesley

Comment: I don't know what else you'd really expect from a still-experimental feature.

Comment: @animuson as far as I know -moz-transform has been available since firefox 3.5 - you would think they'd get the basics down by now.

Comment: You would think, right? The fact is it *is* still experimental and apparently they haven't "gotten it down" yet.

Comment: That's not relevant. Everybody knows vendors are finicky with things like this.

Comment: Have you tried removing the box-shadow? I did that and it animates much more smoothly.

Comment: I use CSS3 transitions a lot, on bigger elements that you are, and I have not had this problem before. But I have never set the `transform-style` property, what happens if you remove that from your CSS?

Comment: I'm interested to see if absolutely positioning the elements helps for everybody: http://jsfiddle.net/QLTbU/. Let me know!

Answer (score 3):

To get your animation boosted, you can remove the `box-shadow` property from `#container .item .thumbnail`, this property is heavy and slows your animation.
But if you still want the shadow effect, you can try putting it behind as a background and not as a part of the animation.

It should take some change, but removing the `box-shadow` property from the animated div will make it faster. The "item zoom" div is the one responsible for the animation. By splitting the "zoom" class from the "item" class, and applying the right css properties on each, the animation shall work faster. (I've tried it with firebug)

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="zoom">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. What exactly do you mean by "behind as a background"? An image?

Comment: It can be whatever you like, as a background image, or in an outer div, on which the animation is not applied.

Comment: Thanks, but even if you put in in an outer div, that has to resize too right? (due to the zooming of the content)

Comment: I'll modify my answer later with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Position your elements absolutely so they are not part of the normal flow of the document. This will make it so the browser doesn't try to redraw the page every-time an animation plays.

When elements are relatively positioned, they can affect each-other when one is changed, so they all have to be redrawn to make sure that changing one element didn't affect all of them.

I created a demo and absolutely positioned the elements, you can see that the animations are much more efficient.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QLTbU/