# Trying to keep animation over 60fps

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, frame-rate

I have a Preloader component in react which has an animation consisting of an svg shaped star and about 30 - 50 randomly generated circles. After a second all the circles are translated to the center of the viewport and the star is scaled down.
I can't keep the animation at 60 fps on screen larger than 20 inch.

At first the star is at 300% width then scaled down to 0.05. On large monitors the scaling eats away about 30% of the GPU causing framerate to drop to 30.

```
.logo-wrapper {
        will-change: transform;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        //display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 300%;
        @include animation('preloader 1s, preloader-shrink 1.5s');
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.51, -0.9, 1, .5);
        animation-delay: 0s, 1.2s;
        transform-origin: center center;
        animation-fill-mode: both;
```

This is the codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwJJzO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [transform: scale immensely slow in all versions of firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183473/transform-scale-immensely-slow-in-all-versions-of-firefox)